# Android Architecture Components LiveData

Tags: android, viewmodel, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I'm trying to implement a simple App using Architecture Components.
I can get the info from RestApi services using Retrofit2. 
I can show the info in the respective Recyclerview and when I rotate the phone everything works as it should.
Now I want to filter by a new kind of object (by string)

Can someone guide me a little with the ViewModel, I don't know what is the best practice to do that...
I'm using MVVM...

This is my ViewModel:

```
public class ListItemViewModel extends ViewModel {
    private MediatorLiveData<ItemList> mList;
    private MeliRepository meliRepository;

    /* Empty Contructor.
     * To have a ViewModel class with non-empty constructor,
     * I have to create a Factory class which would create instance of you ViewModel and
     * that Factory class has to implement ViewModelProvider.Factory interface.
     */
    public ListItemViewModel(){
        meliRepository = new MeliRepository();
    }

    public LiveData<ItemList> getItemList(String query){
       if(mList == null){
           mList = new MediatorLiveData<>();
           LoadItems(query);
       }
    }

    private void LoadItems(String query){
        String queryToSearch = TextUtils.isEmpty(query) ? "IPOD" : query;

        mList.addSource(
                meliRepository.getItemsByQuery(queryToSearch),
                list -> mList.setValue(list)
        );
    }
}
```

**UPDATE**

I resolved this using transformation a package from lifecycle library...
[enter link description here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/livedata.html#transform_livedata)

```
public class ListItemViewModel extends ViewModel {

    private final MutableLiveData<String> mQuery = new MutableLiveData<>();
    private MeliRepository meliRepository;
    private LiveData<ItemList> mList = Transformations.switchMap(mQuery, text -> {
        return meliRepository.getItemsByQuery(text);
    });

    public ListItemViewModel(MeliRepository repository){
        meliRepository = repository;
    }

    public LiveData<ItemList> getItemList(String query){
       return mList;
    }
}
```

@John this is my solution. I'm using lifecycle library and the solution was easier than I thought. Thx!

Answer (score 1):

I'm more familiar with doing this in Kotlin but you should be able to translate this to Java easily enough (or perhaps now is a good time to start using Kotlin :) )....adapting similar pattern I have here I believe you'd do something like:

```
val query: MutableLiveData<String> = MutableLiveData()

val  mList = MediatorLiveData<List<ItemList>>().apply {
    this.addSource(query) {
        this.value = meliRepository.getItemsByQuery(query)
    }
}

fun setQuery(q: String) {
    query.value = q
}
```

I'm using this pattern in following https://github.com/joreilly/galway-bus-android/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/surrus/galwaybus/ui/viewmodel/BusStopsViewModel.kt

Comment: Thx John... I'll try with this!!

Comment: @Guille just curious if you were able to get this working?

Comment: I didn't try yet... I'm "learning" android in my free times... I'll try this weekend and I let you know about it! :)