# how update ViewModel LifeCycle and recyclerview

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-lifecycle

My ViewModel class:

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel { ...
```

I'm initialization from Activity:

```
private void initializeViewModel() {
viewModel = ViewModelProviders
        .of(this, new ViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), argsSelect))
        .get(MyViewModel.class);

viewModel.getLogsList().observe(this, new Observer<List<DebugMessage>>() {
    @Override
    public void onChanged(@Nullable List<DebugMessage> debugMessages) {
        logAdapter.addItems(debugMessages);
    }
});
```

}

My argument (**argsSelect**) changes real time. How me update ViewModel and **RecyclerView** with new SELECT based on current arguments?

Comment: When you say `argsSelect` changes in real time, what's the nature of that change (how/where is it changed?).  Could you perhaps pass it in as argument to `getLogsList()`?  If it's case that you want to dynamically provide a different dependency to `MyViewModel` then consider using `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

Comment: Alternatively, if it's case that `argsSelect` changes after you've called `observe()` (and you want logs list to be updated then to reflect that), then you can use something along the lines of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48307065/android-architecture-components-livedata/48307266#48307266

Comment: args change in moment click button in Activity. Args forming SELECT  logsList = databaseHelper.getDebugMessageDao().select(args);

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Room to load internal data, you have to return a LiveData.

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM user")
fun getAll(): LiveData<MutableList<User>>
```

Every change in your DB will call your observer, so you don't need to worry about it.